# How to compress images before uploading to the cloud using ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

To save space in the cloud how would you go about resizing and compressing an image preupload using activestorage?

Comment: Never tried yet, but I'll do. I suppose you need to enable mini_magick gem and use imagemagick in a callback, maybe: `image.variant(resize: "500x500")`. I found this blog post a useful resource: https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/rails-5-2-active-storage-and-beyond

Comment: Did iGian's solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I tested this code below in development on local storage and it works, but anyway gives some problems that I will explain next.

On create this seems to work fine, even if I suppose there should be a cleaner way to do so.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :avatar

  before_save :resize_avatar_image

  def resize_avatar_image
    filename = avatar.filename.to_s
    puts attachment_path = "#{Dir.tmpdir}/#{avatar.filename}"
    File.open(attachment_path, 'wb') do |file|
       file.write(avatar.download)
       file.close
    end
    image = MiniMagick::Image.open(attachment_path)
    # if image.width ...
    image.resize "40x40"
    image.write attachment_path
    avatar.attach(io: File.open(attachment_path), filename: filename, content_type: "image/jpg")
  end

end
```

**Problems that I encountered that someone could overcome**

1. I was not able to apply variations on the fly without downloading to a temp file in order to process it with MiniMagick
2. When updating (edit) the process is slow because of errors with purge and purge_later methods: `[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::PurgeJob] [d6a930ee-32cd-45a7-bfb5-72929d79f9bb] Error performing ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: d6a930ee-32cd-45a7-bfb5-72929d79f9bb) from Async(default) in 0.33ms: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1))`; I could not find a workaround. **Check if the old blob was deleted.**
3. The problem mentioned at point 2 seems to be related with `.attach` method;
4. I tested only `*.jpg` and `*.png`
5. Not tested in production nor for remote storage

Comment: This just resizes the image right? How can i compress images to save space like when uploading to facebook or whatsapp?