# How to compress images before uploading to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

How can I compress images before uploading like Facebook or Whatsapp do, using Rails Active Storage?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplciate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50844197/how-to-compress-images-before-uploading-to-the-cloud-using-activestorage

Comment: Images are usually already compressed by the image format's algorithm, you'll have little to no benefit compressing an image (only if you reformat it with a format with better compression or the same format with less quality)

Comment: But what I want is to compress even if it looses some quality. For example, in a service that I use, if I upload images with 2Mb it will be compress to around 100Kb. I want to do something like that. It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  imgproxy—a fast and secure standalone server written in Go. 
It does only one thing and does it well: takes care of all your image resizing needs.
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/introducing-imgproxy