# active storage - how to modify file and resave it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am trying to modify uploaded file once it is uploaded but I want to modify it (e.g. do some imagemagick operations on it).

I was trying to download file into tmp directory, modify file and then re-upload it.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this is what you already did, but I'm sharing an old answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50859763/5239030

Comment: I use php and read the image from the temp directory, modify in Imagemagick and save to the new directory; all in one line. Why do you want to download it?

Comment: Because file is either in local storage or S3.